# Spring OAuth2 implicit flow redirect url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

In my Spring Boot/OAuth2 application I'm trying to login user via my own OAuth2 server with implicit flow with a following url:

```
http://example.com/api/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=example_client_id&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin
```

after login it redirects the user to the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/login#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyOTcsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwic2NvcGUiOlsicmVh&token_type=bearer&expires_in=43199&scope=read%20write&user_id=297&jti=9d416117-0d08-4f4e-874d-3f31dbe7815f
```

Is it a correct behavior that the user was redirected to the url with `#` symbol instead of `?`.. I mean:

```
http://localhost:8080/login?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyOTcsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwic2NvcGUiOlsicmVh&token_type=bearer&expires_in=43199&scope=read%20write&user_id=297&jti=9d416117-0d08-4f4e-874d-3f31dbe7815f
```

if no - how to set up my Spring application OAuth2 server in order to redirect user to a correct url ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior is correct. The authorization code flow requires that response parameters be embedded in the **query** part of a redirect URI (RFC 6749, [4.1.2. Authorization Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2)) while the implicit flow requires that response parameters be embedded in the **fragment** part (RFC 6749, [4.2.2. Access Token Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2)).

**[OAuth 2.0 Multiple Response Type Encoding Practices](http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html)** has defined a new request parameter, `response_mode`. The parameter specifies where response parameters should be embedded. In the specification, `query`, `fragment` and `none` are defined. In addition, **[OAuth 2.0 Form Post Response Mode](http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html)** has added `form_post` as a value of `response_mode`. If `response_mode=form_post` is included in an authorization request, response parameters are embedded as HTML form parameters.

You can find a table describing the relationship between `response_type`/`response_mode` combinations and HTTP status/response parameters' location in "[2. Response Format](https://www.authlete.com/documents/definitive_guide/authorization_response#response_format)" in Authlete's Definitive Guide.

[image]